# Please help to check connection, I'm stuck for hours on this already =(

Tags: php, mysql

Can anyone point out if there is any error with this? I was told that there are error and I can only connect through localhost, not through this host name..

I was told that my password set in db.class.php is wrong. Part of the codes are shown below. Appreciated!

```
function __construct($hostname = "192.xx.x.45", $username = "test", $password = "tests", $database = "testing", $prefix = "prefix_", $connector = "mysqli") {
    $this->hostname = !empty($hostname) ? $hostname : "";
    $this->username = !empty($username) ? $username : "";
    $this->password = !empty($password) ? $password : "";
    $this->database = !empty($database) ? $database : "";
    $this->prefix = !empty($prefix) ? $prefix : "";
    $this->connector = !empty($connector) ? $connector : "mysqli";
}

if ($this->config->connector == "mysqli") { 
$this->connection = mysqli_connect($this->config->hostname, $this->config->username, $this->config->password);
$this->selectdb = mysqli_select_db($this->connection, $this->config->database);
}
```

Comment: I even went to w3school to read on it. Everything seems right..

Comment: Exact error message/output? No paraphrasing.

Comment: so why not then use 'localhost' ?

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: You shouldn't look at W3School as the Bible. What errors show up in the PHP logs?

Comment: What error are you getting? Does your "test" MySQL user have privileges to connect through a host other than localhost? Check here to read how users are defined in MySQL: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/account-names.html

Comment: Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'test'@'192.xx.x.36' (using password: YES) in C:\xampp\htdocs\UI\db.class.php on line 59

Warning: mysqli_select_db() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\UI\db.class.php on line 60

Comment: You see, even the host name changes too. that is the headache.. @RolandoIsidoro

Comment: @Dagon I've just completed my intern project, now I have to link it to the company's database.. Thats why..

Comment: is the db on the same server as your script?

Comment: @Dagon Meaning? Well I can connect with all the same credentials through oracle sql developer. that shouldn't be a problem right?

Comment: depends what host the db credentials are set-up for. which is usually localhost only

Comment: @Þaw Error message as shown on top.

Comment: Is it worth pointing out that you're assigning the hostname etc. to properties directly on `$this`, and then accessing them through `$this->config`?

Answer (score 0):

From the error messages you're getting, your problem is that the database user you're using to connect to MySQL does not have the privileges to connect from the IP of the server you are accessing your database from.

You need to modify your database user to allow it to connect to your MySQL database from any IP, or just your server's IP. As mentioned, check the MySQL manual for this:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/account-names.html

Also, you will need to make sure that the firewall of the MySQL server allows connections from other servers to the MySQL port (3306, by default).

Comment: I'm using the company's computer, and their connection. So I suppose this shouldn't be the reason right? I'm not sure about it actually. So I have to talk to the programmer to have him allow anyone to connect to it?